# How to map ctrl+enter to type "<br>"

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In VS Code, I would like to hit Ctrl+Enter to type "<br>". Nothing else.

It is currently inserting and going to a new line. I've looked through Keyboard Shortcuts and User Snippets. Neither quite does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the [Insert <br> Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/itemdetails?itemName=1natsu.insert-br-tag) extension. Now when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> you will insert a <br> tag.
2. Open File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.
3. Search for "<br>" in the list of shortcuts and set the "Insert <br> Tag" command keybinding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.